# How to get a reference to a table row with a specific value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to highlight just one specific row in a table using jQuery. The row will have an 'active' status. I have seen plenty of examples online which show how to do zebra striping for alternate row styling. Does anyone know of a jQuery expression which will get a  element based on the value of a  element in a specific column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out ":contains" on http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: Perfect. Every time I start to think something will be complicated w/ jQuery, there's a one-liner that gets it done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of them:

```
$("td").contains("test");
```

or

```
$("div:contains('John')");
```

Comment: Can't get $("td").contains("test") to work. Though $("div:contains('John')") is OK.